# Virtual Box - Shared folder issue with Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, shared-folders

I have a Virtual Box GUI Version 5.1.14r112924 (Qt5.6.2) with a Guest OS Ubuntu-16.04.2 (64-bit) and as a host OS Windows 7 Enterprise.

My shared folder functionality and the ClipBoard mode used to work, but a few days ago, without an update from any component, the shared folder on my Guest OS was empty, while it was containing a lot of files on my host OS.

I installed the guest additions (5.2.8_KernelUbuntu r120774):

[image: Session Information]

And the folder is configured like this:

[image]

So the files from my C:/LocalData/Share should be available in /media/sf_Share/ but this is not the case :(

I tried to restart the Guest OS, update the Guest Additions from an ISO image (this also gave troubles):

[image]

I already tried to remove the Optical Drive from the Virtual Box and to read it, nothing helped. I could run the ISO from the mounted drive, but this also gave me an issue:

Because it was still mounted I could install it from there but it gave me errors.

What did work be to install them using apt-get:

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-additions-iso
```

I also made sure that my user is added to the vboxsf group

sudo usermod -G vboxsf -a

And the rights are ok on the folder:

[image]

This installed them, but I cannot find a way to access the files on my host OS :(

I put a lot of effort into setting up my guest OS and configuring everything. I want to avoid to start over the config just for not being able to share files and copy text between host and guest OS.

Is there something else I could try?

Comment: Is the shard folder listed with the `mount` command on the guest?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Were you able to successfully restart the guest os?  That is necessary to be able to see `sf_Share` through the Auto-mount option.  In the Guest OS you can run:

```
sudo mkdir ~/Share
sudo mount -t vboxsf Share ~/Share
```

to make it available in the guest OS as `~/Share`

References

- https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-share-folders-between-guest-and-host-in-virtualbox/
- http://www.giannistsakiris.com/2008/04/09/virtualbox-access-windows-host-shared-folders-from-ubuntu-guest/

Comment: Thank you! I restarted it, not problems there, but it only worked again after I executed the command: sudo mount -t vboxsf Share /media/sf_Share Thank you for your help.